# Can't make figures to be automatically saved in R from sections of database?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code seems to run but doesn't stop and I can't get the files to be saved on the desktop folder "graph" on my mac.

```
i <- 1L
for (i in 1:nrow(p)) {
mypath <- file.path("/Users/atreyu/Desktop/graphs/",paste("DATA_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
jpeg(file=mypath)
dsmall <- p[i:(i+10),]
qplot(dsmall$o, dsmall$t)
dev.off()
i <- i+10
}
```

Basically, I want to create a gallery of figures done on sections of my data. Each section consists of 10 rows.

The code is in R, and p is a data frame with about 100k rows. How can I write a more efficient code?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code to the following (I just want to know how to do for loop for saving graphs, and I still can't seem to be able to save graphs, I can save one graph, but not using for loop)

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(p)))
{
mypath <- file.path("/Users/atreyu/Desktop/graphs",paste("DATA_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
dsmall <- p[i:(i+10),]
jpeg(filename = mypath)
qplot(dsmall$c, dsmall$t)
dev.off()
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I figured out that this works:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(p)))
{
mypath <- file.path("/Users/atreyu/Desktop/graphs")
dsmall <- p[i:(i+10),]
jpeg(filename = paste(mypath,"DATA_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
plot(dsmall$c, dsmall$t)
dev.off()
}
```

I figured out that you can do the loop on plot but not on qplot. How strange is that?

Comment: You should **strongly** reconsider creating 100000 graphics files. First off, why do it? You couldn’t possibly look at all these files, so it seems a bit useless. But equally importantly, having 100000 files in the same path will tax the file system substantially: file systems are optimised for relatively few files per node. Having so many in a single directory will slow the file system to a crawl. (EDIT: Ah, it’s supposed to create only 10000 files. That will be less of a problem for the file system but I think it’s similarly unreasonable.)

Comment: I have an strong reason to do this. These files will be zipped, pickled and fed into another software. R, here is only used to make those figures. Do you suggest any better software (other than R) to do this. I'm not an R person and picked up R today just to do this, as I couldn't figure out a better software for this?

Comment: R isn’t the problem. The problems are the two things I mentioned in my previous comment. Honestly, the downstream software seems badly conceived: why doesn’t it instead accept the *raw data* and create the desired plots on the fly?

Comment: Yes, that software sucks. It's an old software.

Comment: Your code didn't work because calling `qplot` doesn't print graph to the open `jpeg` device. you can do `print(qplot(...))`, but using `ggsave` as suggested below is better

Answer (score 1):

First, remove:

```
i <- i+10
```

Never modify the loop counter unless you are using a `while` loop.

Change

```
dsmall <- p[i:i+9,]
```

to

```
dsmall <- p[i:(i+9),]
```

This requires then that:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(p))
```

goes to:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(p)-9))
```

Lastly, to really help, it is great to give a sample of the data by using:

```
dput(data_here)
```

**Edit**

Per discussion in the comments, the asker really wants to modify the `i` index in the following manner:

```
for(i in seq(1, nrow(p), by = 10))
```

**Redux**

The following produces 92 individual graphs in the `user` directory (`~/`).

```
library(ggplot2)
n = 1e2
p = data.frame(c = rnorm(n), t = rnorm(n))

for (i in 1:(nrow(p)-9)) { 
  mypath <- file.path("~",paste0("DATA_", i, ".jpg")) 
  dsmall <- p[i:(i+9),] 
  a = qplot(dsmall$c, dsmall$t) 
  ggsave(mypath, a)
}
```

Please make sure that you have created the export directory via:

```
 dir.create("/Users/atreyu/Desktop/graphs", recursive = T)
```

Comment: I want i to jump 10 rows every time, I don't want it to jump one by one? Then you suggest to not use for loop and go for while loop then, right?

Comment: So you want a jump of 10 rows each time then? Then, you should use:

`seq(1, nrow(p), by = 10)`, which will give the following values for `i`:
`[1]  1 11 21 31 41 51 61 71 81 91`

Comment: If you want `i` to increment by 10, you will need to switch the `1:nrow(p)` to what I mentioned above. Also, you will want to switch the subset `(i+10)` to `(i+9)` to avoid going out of bounds on the last iteration.

Comment: I don't care about the incrementation anymore right now, It would be fine to do single incrementation as well. I updated my code, on the original question and applied your suggestions, but I still can't get the code to save the figures.

Comment: I made a quick reproducible example for you. If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: That's great. Please read the update 2 in my original question, my code works with plot but not qplot. I will try your code asap.

Comment: @Antaeus try the above modification. Everything should work now with the `ggsave()` function.